# How to edit default page in wordpress?(index page)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to edit default page in WordPress site?(index page).
I am inspecting the current page, and find that the code is in index page.
But there is no way to find where is the file located.
The site hosted on hostinger. Then I am trying to edit other pages other than default page? Is there is a way to find the index page?

Comment: simi on folder index.php is default page so you have change in this page

Comment: Is there is a way to edit these index page via Appearance-> Editor, How to find it ?

Answer (score 1):

For editing on index page in wordpress you can find it in wordpress theme,
go to wp-content >> your current theme and edit index page.

Answer (score 1):

To edit home page on wordpres :
Go to : wp-content/themes/your-main-theme/index.php
.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like only edit some part of the code you can use this url

your_address/wp-admin/theme-editor.php

or in your dashboard as admin user:
Appearance -> Editor

Answer (score 0):

there can be more then one way to edit a Wordpress website. The best way is to create a "Child Theme", [here](https://woocommerce.com/2013/10/wordpress-customization/) are some good instructions on it. This way the main theme can still be updated without loosing your changes. Wordpress is a Content Management System so most likely you will be able to make a lot of changes via the admin panel. The link I added has more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Your index page is like a template where you put things to it. Go Settings->Reading->FrontPage, and you can set any of your existing page to be your homepage. Is that what you want to change?

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Here is some info how files are loaded. And file hierarchy explained. In your situation every new you page uses a page.php template.For example in this case,  you should create homepage.php in your theme, copy the content from page.php, and clear that part where `<div>` contains sidebar as id.

Comment: Front page is already selected as static page ,The selected page is newly created.But the page contain some other things like categories,meta etc by inspecting could find that these are from index page. But how to reach index page? Is there any way in Appearance- >editor?

Comment: I do not recommend to use Appearance- >editor, but i think you need a template for your homepage. Your current empty page is inherited from page.php file, which is a template for all your pages.

Comment: To edit categories & meta, these are under widgets, appearance > widgets

Comment: some theme doesn't show the widgets in appearance > widgets

Comment: <img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ; ?>/images/slides/slider3.jpg" alt="" title="#slidecaption3" />.If i ant to add new pic like this. how it possible?could you plz help me?

Comment: Try adding your code to your page.php file in your current theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Source HTML/PHP code thru the built in "editor" under "appearance" in your back-end dashboard, by selecting your pages/templates. Alternatively you may FTP into the server and DIRECT edit the HTML code within your homepage.php, etc files with a text editor.

Answer (score -1):

Option one:
Download the theme. Then open any file of that theme in file editor. Then search for/find (Ctrl+F) that code/text you are looking for. Select option in which file or folder search for. It will locate the code with file location.

Option Two:
If you have FTP access by using FileZilla you will be able to find the file by searching for the code/text.